# platform.js from polymers template binding

Tags: polymer

In the platform.js from polymer is a 
[template binding](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html) described.

Then is my understanding that the platform.js contains polyfills for later implemented browser features.

Is the template bind a feature that will later supported by browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been talks of taking `Node.bind()` through the standards process, but there's currently no movement on that front. This is why all the template/data binding  stuff is part of Polymer core and not the platform.js polyfill/prollyfill layer.

Comment: It would be better if the core content would seperated in a ploymer-core.js and not contained in the platform.js. It is more then confusing what is a polyfill and what not.

Comment: That's what my description says... It's already the case AFAIK. There may still be bits that are lingering in platform.js that sf shouldn't be there.